# Tooltips for Button elements

Tags: html, button, tooltip

Is it possible to create a tooltip for an html button. Its the normal HTML button and there is no Title attribute as it is there for some html controls. Any thoughts or comments?

Answer (score 776, accepted):

Simply add a `title` to your `button`.

```html
<button title="Hello World!">Sample Button</button>
```

Comment: @EduardLuca, In my case tooltip really does no work on `disabled` buttons because Bootstrap sets `pointer-events: none` for disabled state. It should work if set `pointer-events: auto` directly to the element.

Comment: it's also that, the tooltip will aim to show bottom from where the mouse is. So if the target element is on the bottom right of the screen then the tooltip scrambles over the mouse pointer. More generally: the position of the tip isn't smart sometimes... but I guess that's just the browsers then.

Comment: [There are situations where tooltips are necessary](https://inclusive-components.design/tooltips-toggletips/#acasefortooltips), but [it is important to consider your userbase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title#Accessibility_concerns) when using the method in this answer. I used the `title` attribute for showing a keyboard shortcut for a button because shortcuts aren't necessary and touch only devices don't use keyboards.

Comment: but this doesn't show tooltip when you use keyboard to focus the button, any other trick to handle this? I guess this is accessibility issue, no?

Comment: Reference: [HTML Living Standard 3.2.6.1 The title attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#attr-title).

Answer (score 49):

both `<button>` tag and `<input type="button">` accept a title attribute..

Comment: What about for plain HTML links using `<a>` and `href`?

Comment: @AaronFranke yes `a` tags as well as all tags support the `title` attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

Answer (score 36):

Use `title` attribute.
It is a standard HTML attribute and is by default rendered in a tooltip by most desktop browsers.

Comment: The issue that I am reading though highlights that the title attribute is not fully supported by many mobile browsers. I'm currently researching this as well for some ADA issues and it seems to be only somewhat supported.

Comment: @isaacweathers Well, how would you "hover" in a mobile browser, anyway, in order to view the title?

Comment: @mbomb007 -- :focus state on iOS with voiceover is about as close to :hover attribute as you could get.

Comment: [Links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer. When someone goes on Stack Exchange, the question "answer" should actually contain an answer. Not just a bunch of directions towards the answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/171858)

Answer (score 24):

A button accepts a "title" attribute. You can then assign it the value you want to make a label appear when you hover the mouse over the button.

```html
<button type="submit" title="Login">
Login</button>
```

Comment: what does the title here?

Answer (score 14):

For everyone here seeking a **crazy solution**, just simply try

```
title="your-tooltip-here"
```

in **any tag**. I've tested into `td`'s and `a`'s and it pretty works.

Comment: @krillgar, I gave a general solution that works not only with _button_ but other tags. My intention was reinforce this possibility.

Comment: regarding your last comment, it's already what skyman's answer was saying years ago.

Answer (score 2):

The title attribute is meant to give more information. It's not useful for SEO so it's never a good idea to have the same text in the title and alt which is meant to describe the image or input is vs. what it does. for instance:

```
<button title="prints out hello world">Sample Buttons</button>

<img title="Hms beagle in the straits of magellan" alt="HMS Beagle painting" src="hms-beagle.jpg" />
```

The title attribute will make a tool tip, but it will be controlled by the browser as far as where it shows up and what it looks like. If you want more control there are third party jQuery options, many css templates such as Bootstrap have built in solutions, and you can also write a simple css solution if you want. check out this [w3schools solution](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_tooltip.asp).

Answer (score 1):

If your button still doesn't show anything with `title`, check if your button is NOT `disabled`

Answer (score -2):

You should use **both** **title** and **alt** attributes to make it work in all browsers.

```
<button title="Hello World!" alt="Hello World!">Sample Button</button>
```

Comment: Why should you use both?

Comment: because some browser use alt attribute and some title

Comment: Nonsense. The `alt` attribute is only valid for `img`, `input type="image"` and `area` tags.