# can the alt attribute be used for an input type button

Tags: html

I wanna ask about the alt attribute in an input tag.
As I found on many sites, the alt attribute is used when we have an input with type image.

1/ Can it be used for an input type button?

```
<input type="button" alt="myAction.myMethod" />
```

2/ what is its meaning?

Comment: Why would you use it with a button input anyway?

Comment: This attribute is used for `<img>

Comment: Perhaps if you mention what you want to achieve with this, hints could be given as to what tag you should be using.

Comment: Do you actually want to ask how to set some text in an `input` element of type `button`?

Comment: The ask perhaps for accessibility. No, we can't add alt text because it doesn't make sense with the button, but for accessibility, we can add aria-label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No
2. It doesn't have one

The only kind of input that can have an `alt` attribute is `type="image"` where it provides a text alternative for when the image can't be rendered (e.g. because it failed to load, because the browser doesn't support images, or because the user is employing screen reader software (usually to compensate for a vision related disability)).

Answer (score 31):

The attribute that defines the mouse hover **tooltip** text is `title`, not `alt`, as asked and answered in [Tooltips for Button elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238239/tooltips-for-button).

The `title` attribute documentation page at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title (MDN) also has a few notes about accessibility issues for the tooltip effect on mouse over and suggests some alternative techniques.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_alt.asp 
I quote

> The alt attribute provides an alternate text for the user, if he/she
>   for some reason cannot view the image (because of slow connection, an
>   error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).
>
> Note: The alt attribute can only be used with <input type="image">.

So, no. And since it cannot be used with a button, it has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

For a button class I found it was `title="Copy to clipboard"` that worked for me.