# Use of alt in button tag

Tags: javascript, html

I came across this line of code

```
<button onclick="Set_Delete()" id="btnDelete" alt="submit" >Delete</button>
```

I'm not able to understand what is the use of alt in a button tag. Can anyone elaborate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423029/can-the-alt-attribute-be-used-for-an-input-type-button

Comment: i don't know button have `alt`.I think its image tag only have a alt or `type="image"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can the alt attribute be used for an input type button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423029/can-the-alt-attribute-be-used-for-an-input-type-button)

Answer (score 0):

The alt attribute provides an alternate text for the user, if he/she for some reason cannot view the image (because of slow connection, an error in the src attribute, or if the user uses a screen reader).

Note: The alt attribute can only be used with input type image and code in your question is **Invalid**

Comment: I thought so too but this code is live on a very big product

Comment: All code in big project is not completely correct. wrong attributes not caused to stopped working. you can see complete alt attribute usage in https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_alt.asp @Sarabjeetsingh

Comment: I'll inform the team then. Thanks