# Button Suggestion message

Tags: html, css

I am going to ask a pretty simple question.

**`How to make a simple button suggestion message !!`**

I have search a lot how to do that but strangely did not find anything at all to do that.

For example this is a button.

```
<button type="button")>Search !</button>
```

Now when the cursor come upon this button how can it show a message or a **suggestion** that `"Hit Search button !"`

Anyone knows any simple solution to this !!

Comment: Do you mean a title? Try ``<button type="button" title="Hit Search button!">Search !</button>``

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tooltips for Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238239/tooltips-for-button)

Answer (score 1):

Just Simply try this

```
<button type="button" title="Hit Search button !">Search !</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking something like this;

html

```
<button type="button")><span>Search !<span></button>
```

css

```
 button:hover span { display: none; }
 button:hover:after {
  content: "Hit Search button !!";
 }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/obNrxw

But I'm not 100% sure of understanding your question