# Is it possible to display the description of a button when hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

In my Angular program, I want to display a string of text that says what the button does whenever you hover over the button.

How do I do this?

[image: Here's a picture of what I'm talking about.]

My mouse is hovering over the google button.

Here's my `html` code for one of my buttons if it helps:

```html
          <button [disabled]="!isDisabled" name="enable" class="btn btn-default btn-margin" (click)="toggleDisabled()"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: did you try the title attribute?
example here
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_title

Comment: @KaranGarg I was unaware of that, thanks - works perfectly! if you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try the title attribute?

```
title="hello world"
```

example here

http://w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_title

Answer (score 2):

You can use title

```html
          <button [disabled]="!isDisabled" name="enable" class="btn btn-default btn-margin" (click)="toggleDisabled()" title="Something"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
title="my tooltip text"
```

or

```
[title]="aPropertyWithTooltipContent"
```

see also [tooltips for Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238239/tooltips-for-button)