# How add tooltip for disabed button ? (reactstrap)

Tags: web, frontend, markup

How add tooltip for disabled dropdown button. I use reactstrap.

Comment: What have you tried ? what are your issues ? Share efforts please

Answer (score 2):

Disable the pointerEvents on the disabled button, so you're actually hovering on span instead of buttons:

```
<span id="foo">
    <Button disabled style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>nope!</Button>
</span>
<Tooltip target="foo" ...etc>Button is disabled</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if drop down buttons behave the same as regular buttons, bur for a regular button, you can wrap the button in a `div`, and set the tooltip to target the `div`.

```
<div id='foo'>
  <Button disabled>nope!</Button>
</div>
<Tooltip target='foo' ...etc>Button is disabled</Tooltip>
```

Comment: I've noticed this only works if the button doesn't completely fill the `div`.

Comment: or, the button's title attribute.  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238239/tooltips-for-button