# HTML input tag: how to have lots of text for title attribute?

Tags: html, html-input, html-title

**Question**

What is the best way to have lots of text for the `title` attribute within the HTML input type `button`?

Currently I literally just have lots of text, but this results in very long lines of HTML code.  For example:

```
<input id="DoSomething" type="button" name="DoSomething" value="Do Something" title="This a shadow of the amount of text one can put as the title.">
```

**My Use Case**

Why use lots of text for the `title` attribute?  Because I'm trying to have instructions about the button's purpose within a tooltip.  My webpage is crowded, and I don't want to list the text as a paragraph, external to the button.  I am open to other ideas.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238299/11163122

Comment: I think this is a coding/programming, and more a user-experience, problem. As such this may be worth asking [ux.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this could either be done with Javascript, as follows:

```js
var inputDoSomething = document.getElementById('DoSomething');
inputDoSomething.setAttribute('title', 'This a shadow of the amount of text one can put as the title.');
```

```html
<input id="DoSomething" type="button" name="DoSomething" value="Do Something">
```

Or via your backend file (I am assuming C#), like so:

**C#**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DoSomething.Attributes.Add("title","This a shadow of the amount of text one can put as the title.");
}
```

**HTML in .ASPX file**

```
<input id="DoSomething" type="button" name="DoSomething" value="Do Something" runat="server">
```

Comment: Thank you @EGC, that's a great idea with Javascript!